# Can't build pyPortMidi on mac

Tags: python, macos

I have installed python-2.7-macosx10.5.dmg from python.org on Mac os x 10.5.8.

I'm issuing: python setup.py build for pyPortMidi-0.0.3

And getting:

```
Found darwin (OS X) platform
running build
running build_ext
pyrexc pypm.pyx --> pypm.c
/Users/baz/Downloads/pyPortMidi-0.0.3/pypm.pyx:357:21: Type 'PmError' not acceptable as a boolean
building 'pypm' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c pypm.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-intel-2.7/pypm.o
pypm.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Pyrex compilation.
pypm.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Pyrex compilation.
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/oO/oO1flrWgHAC8u6KdoO0Wq++++TI/-Tmp-//ccTcgy0s.out
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: look at the notes here:
http://cratel.wichita.edu/cratel/cratel%20pyportmidi#build_on_OS_X

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way was to build the version of pyPortMidi included in pygame, which has some fixes applied.

You can use the following pattern to import it at the top of your file, preferring the standard version, but falling back to the pygame bundled version.

```
try:
    import pypm
except ImportError:
    from pygame import pypm
```

Using MacPorts, it was easy to install using:

```
port install py27-game +portmidi
```

I don't know if you need something special to include portmidi in the build if you build by other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link below it seems that stuff is broken and missing. Don't know if they are going to fix it anytime soon... Been bothering me too for some time...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pygame-mirror-on-google-groups/sf3I8Q-wYQA